# image pop up on a steady position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the right syntax to make my pop up image show on the left side of the screen?

**jQuery**

```
$("#qm3").mouseover(function(){
    $("#osf").show();
});
$("#qm3").mouseout(function(){
    $("#osf").hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<span><input type="text" id="tb1"><img id="qm3" src="images/WebResource.png"></img></span><span><img id="osf" src="images/osf.jpg" style="position: right; display:none;"></img></span>
```

As of now, whenever I'm pointing my mouse to `qm3`, the pop up shows, but it affects the positioning of my page.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vENZeK

Comment: `position: right` is an invalid property declaration. Instead, you should look at using absolute positioning, i.e. `position: absolute`. However, without your CSS code and a mockup of the intended visual appearance, it's difficult to help.

Comment: Can you please include a fiddle or codepen; this will help get your question answered.

Comment: i've added the codepen...

Answer (score 0):

This could be simplified, if you get rid of the spans and wrap a div around it:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPygOg

js

```
$(".show").hover(function(){
 $(this).next('img.hide').fadeToggle();
});
```

html

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="tb1">
  <img class='show' src="http://placekitten.com/42/41"/>
  <img class="hide" src="http://placekitten.com/40/41"/>
</div>
```

css

```
div { postition:relative; padding-left:45px;}
.hide { display:none;  position:absolute; left:5px; }
```